# Backup mysql database using java

Tags: java, mysql, database

My application contains one java frame for backup.I add the following code in a public class and call that.My need is to create the MySQL dump file in application.How can i do that using java code,The following set of code will give you what exactly do in my program.

```
  public boolean backupDB() {

    connection = (Connection) dbSource.getConnection();


    String executeCmd = "\"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysqldump\"  -u root -p pass macfast -r backup.sql";
    Process runtimeProcess;
    try {

        runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

I call this by

```
 private void backupbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    backupDB();
}
```

It stuck when i am trying to run.After run i can't close the frame.only possible through taskmanager.why?

Comment: You might have to run "C:\\Program Files\\mysql\\mysqldump", or something like that.

Comment: i edited (path) my qstn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the mysqldump is on your system PATH environment variable

The error suggests that it can't find that program, which means it is likely looking in the working directory.

Comment: How can i check whether the mysqldump is on your system PATH environment variable?

Comment: A bat file created as @echo off
set datefix=%DATE%
set datefix=%DATE:/=-%

mysqldump -u root -p pass mydb > C:\Program Files\mbaplus\backup.sql
exit. but does not work

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with full path to utility ?

```
/<fullpath>/mysqldump -u
```

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: if white space in path is problem, use windows short path e.g. - C:\PROGRA~1\MySQL\MYSQLS~1.1\bin

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is the white space between ...Program Files..., you'll need to enclose the path in "

Change `String executeCmd = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysqldump  -u root -p pass macfast -r backup.sql";`

to

```
String executeCmd = "\"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysqldump\"  -u root -p pass macfast -r backup.sql";
```

Comment: edited my program by your suggested code.But it stuck.i cant close the frame

Comment: Without any Java Exception? Is the database quite small? Perhaps you should also add the full path to the mysqldump output and make sure this folder is writeable

Comment: Database having 3 tables with values

Comment: could you please tell me about where actually the backup.dump stores?

Comment: Does adding "cmd \\c " before your String executeCmd help?

Comment: I am basically an android dev.So please help me.or suggest edit my code